# UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource Animations

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

Is it true that there’s no way to animate cells being added and removed using a UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource like there is using a UITableViewDiffableDataSource ? Looks like the tableView version has defaultRowAnimation property but nothing exists like this for the CollectionView version. Ideally I would like to get the cell collapsing/expanding animation you get from the tableView .default animation style

Comment: You could always do this yourself (check out Core Animation/Layers/etc./etc.).  I've done a lot of one-off animation work within iOS - pretty straight forward to accomplish once you understand the role of the layer on a view, and using explicit animations (versus implied, which happen when you invoke an animated property, for example).